# How can I permanently get X/Y position of my finger on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I tried this with "touchstart" , "touchmove" and "touchend", but all these events are only fired once. How can I get "touchmove" to fire permanently?

Comment: Does this work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204460/the-touchmove-event-on-android-system-transformer-prime

Comment: Wow thanks a lot.. i've googled a really long time but i never found that bug. Thank you!