# Touchmove and webgl controls conflict

Tags: javascript, android, three.js, touch

I have been using and modifying the nice distance measuring tool created by Markus Schuetz for point clouds, but which also works for meshes.

Demo: http://potree.org/demo/distance_measure/examples/distance_measure.html

Github: https://github.com/potree/potree/tree/master/examples

However, I would also like to enable it for use on mobile devices. I think the main addition is that the current function is only:

```
function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
}
```

And therefore there needs to be a further function for touchmoves, such as:

```
function onDocumentTouchMove(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        mouse.x = (event.touches[0].pageX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = -(event.touches[0].pageY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
}
```

As well as an accompanying listener:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false);
```

However, this does not seem to be sufficient. On Android KitKat at least, this does successfully allow the moving of the ‘start’ and ‘end’ landmarks, but the touchmoves are still creating conflicts with the webgl model panning/rotating. I had been hoping that event.preventDefault(); would avoid this issue (and as an alternative I have also tried using event.stopPropagation)

Do I also need to add touchStart and touchEnd functions to make this work properly?

Comment: You possibly need to modify `OrbitControls` for your specific needs (they are example implementations after all).

If you're adding your own handlers you can possibly work around it by temporarily disabling the controls with `controls.enabled = false` and restoring that setting when your event is complete.

And by the way, you're using `68dev` rather than `r68`.

Comment: `68dev` is from the demo Markus has posted. I thought it simpler to refer to his original example rather than to my implementation as the latter will definitely be updated (but for info is [here](http://micropasts.org/3D/)). Toggling `controls.enabled=false` does not seem to sort the problem, but I'll keep looking. It may be related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204460/the-touchmove-event-on-android-system-transformer-prime?rq=1).

Comment: Are you disabling the controls in an `onTouchStart` or an `onTouchMove` handler? You need the former. Also, you probably need to attach your handler (assuming it's outside of `OrbitControls`) before you initialise the controls, or your own event will most likely fire **after** `touchstart` in `OrbitControls` and that's a bit late to disable it.